# Not Rolling Back Spring Transaction From ZK

Tags: spring, hibernate, zk

I am facing a problem while calling the service method written in Spring Sevice that is injected in MVVM in that method I am saving one object and after that doing some other value fatching method call that throw exception and I want that while throwing that exception my Transaction rollback my service method part are as under `CeilingServiceIMPL`:

```
    CeilingSheet ceilingSheet = new CeilingSheet();
    ceilingSheet.setFiscalYear(fiscalYear);
    ceilingSheet.setStatus(ECeilingSheetStatus.NEW);
    ceilingSheet = saveCeilingSheet(ceilingSheet).getResult();

    CeilingCategory ceilingCategory1 = null;
    try {
        ceilingCategory1 = categoryQueryService.findCeilingCategoryByCode(
                "01").getResult();
    } catch (ObjectNotFoundException ex) {
        throw new RequestException(1234, ceilingCategory1);
    }
```

if RequestException throws , I am expecting that my record that I saved before also rollback. I have making the service Transaction by annotating as

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor =  RequestException.class)
```

The bean is injected with

```
@WireVariable(ICeilingSheetService.NAME) private ICeilingSheetService ceilingSheetService;
```

When I tried this method to call from junit test case it rolling back fine , but when I integrate it with ZK zul page and View Model by autowired services it stop rolling back and even if my code throws RequestException my CeilingSheet are persisting.
My ZK web.xml is

```
    <!-- Spring can be easily integrated into any Java-based web framework. 
    All you need to do is to declare the ContextLoaderListener in your web.xml 
    and use a contextConfigLocation <context-param> to set which context files 
    to load. If you don't specify the contextConfigLocation context parameter, 
    the ContextLoaderListener will look for a /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml 
    file to load. Once the context files are loaded, Spring creates a WebApplicationContext 
    object based on the bean definitions and puts it into the ServletContext. -->

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
             /WEB-INF/application-context.xml
     </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- LOGGER -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4j-config-location</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Loads the Spring web application context -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- end of spring configuration -->

<description><![CDATA[My ZK Application]]></description>
<display-name>IFMIS User Interface</display-name>

<!-- //// -->
<!-- ZK -->
<listener>
    <description>ZK listener for session cleanup</description>
    <listener-class>org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.HttpSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <description>ZK loader for ZUML pages</description>
    <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet</servlet-class>

    <!-- Must. Specifies URI of the update engine (DHtmlUpdateServlet). It 
        must be the same as <url-pattern> for the update engine. -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>update-uri</param-name>
        <param-value>/zkau</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <!-- Optional. Specifies whether to compress the output of the ZK loader. 
        It speeds up the transmission over slow Internet. However, if you configure 
        a filter to post-processing the output, you might have to disable it. Default: 
        true <init-param> <param-name>compress</param-name> <param-value>true</param-value> 
        </init-param> -->
    <!-- [Optional] Specifies the default log level: OFF, ERROR, WARNING, INFO, 
        DEBUG and FINER. If not specified, the system default is used. <init-param> 
        <param-name>log-level</param-name> <param-value>OFF</param-value> </init-param> -->
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup><!-- Must -->
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.zul</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.zhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!-- [Optional] Uncomment it if you want to use richlets. <servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name> <url-pattern>/zk/*</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping> -->
<servlet>
    <description>The asynchronous update engine for ZK</description>
    <servlet-name>auEngine</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet</servlet-class>

    <!-- [Optional] Specifies whether to compress the output of the ZK loader. 
        It speeds up the transmission over slow Internet. However, if your server 
        will do the compression, you might have to disable it. Default: true <init-param> 
        <param-name>compress</param-name> <param-value>true</param-value> </init-param> -->
    <!-- [Optional] Specifies the AU extension for particular prefix. <init-param> 
        <param-name>extension0</param-name> <param-value>/upload=com.my.MyUploader</param-value> 
        </init-param> -->
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>auEngine</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/zkau/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My application-context.xml

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/database.properties</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/msg-database.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />

<context:annotation-config />


<context:component-scan base-package="my.service" />

<import resource="hibernate-context.xml" />
```

My hibernat-context.xml

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass">
        <value>${jdbc.driverClassName}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="jdbcUrl">
        <value>${jdbc.url}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="user">
        <value>${jdbc.username}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${jdbc.password}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${jdbc.maxPoolSize}" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="${jdbc.minPoolSize}" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="${jdbc.maxStatements}" />
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="${jdbc.testConnection}" />
</bean>

<!-- bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"> 
    <property name="driverClassName"> <value>${driverClassName}</value> </property> 
    <property name="url"> <value>${url}</value> </property> <property name="username"> 
    <value>${username}</value> </property> <property name="password"> <value>${password}</value> 
    </property> </bean -->

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>my.domain.class</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes">${jadira.usertype}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
```

Please advice ...

Answer (score 0):

The first step in such cases is always to enable logging at level `DEBUG` for `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager`. That will show you what Spring is doing and why.

For example, it will show you when it detects an exception and when it does a rollback or a commit. You can also set breakpoints in this code to see what is going on. It's pretty straightforward.

Knowing a bit about ZK, my guess is that you have `new CeilingServiceIMPL()` somewhere in the ZK code because you couldn't figure out how to inject Spring beans into a controller. This effectively renders all `@Transactional` useless.

You must get the bean from spring. Check out http://www.zkoss.org/product/zkspring and the documentation at [Using Spring Variable Resolver](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Spring%20Essentials/Working%20with%20ZK%20Spring/Working%20with%20ZK%20Spring%20Core/Using%20Spring%20Variable%20Resolver) how to wire beans with ZK.

Comment: Thanks Aaron for response , I am injecting beans service in ZK Controller using ZK Auto-wired Annotation.
Code snipped  for controller to auto-wired spring service :

@WireVariable(ICeilingSheetService.NAME)
private ICeilingSheetService ceilingSheetService;

This will wire my bean service in ZK controller and works fine for all activity other then rollback while exception.

Comment: Then what do you see in the debug log?

Comment: It would be good to add the injection code and the bean definition to the question.

Comment: In the dubug log it is showing that Exception thrown with name of the exception but record persisted also which should not be persist.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the method call and make sure spring does intercept the call. You should end up in `TransactionInterceptor` instead of calling the method directly. See also http://blog.jhades.org/how-does-spring-transactional-really-work/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :
Reason : In My application we have the requirement to show the User messages based on the number thrown by the exception , for this we have a separate message-hibernate-context.xml file with seperate

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="messageSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

and one is already with hibernate-context.xml

```
    <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

and the above both xml file called from my application-context.xml as

```
<import resource="hibernate-context.xml" />
<import resource="message-hibernate-context.xml" />
```

So after code thrown exception based on key thrown , my user-message bean trying to load separate Transaction Manager and old transaction committed and new Hibernate session starts that was going to rollback and since this is new Transaction so It does not found anything to rollback.

Once I removed other Transaction Manager it start working . 
Thanks All for support...